# How to use <base> tag in html5 for specific anchor tags only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have **one** base tag in head and there are two different anchor tags as follows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href="https://www.youtube.com"/>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="/embed/xDMP3i36naA?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <img src="img/1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
</body>
```

And i want to use the **url** in the base tag for a specific anchor tag, how do i do that ?

Thanks,

Comment: type the base url in your attribute.

Comment: the base url defined in the head is being applied to all the anchors on the page, i was wondering if there is any way to target the base url to the specific anchor or source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this for a specific anchor tag only it is not possible, you can use as a workaround for that such as giving the specific anchors a class and creating a javascript function that loops through these anchors on document load, update their `href` attributes and prepend the base URL specifcally.

Using the HTML tag applies to all the website not to specific anchors:

The base tag provides base location from which links on a page should be made. Relative links within a document (such as `<a href="someplace.html"… or <img src="someimage.jpg"…` ) will become relative to the URL specified by the base element.

**UPDATE**

Below is a non-tested example, knowing that the base tag shall be removed:

```
    var specificBaseURL = 'http://www.example.com/';

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".specific_anchor").each(function(){

          $(this).attr("href", specificBaseURL + $(this).attr("href"));

        }); 
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <a class="specific_anchor" href="path1/">...</a>
   <a href="non/specific/path2">...</a>
   <a class="specific_anchor" href="path3/">...</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , i wonder if there is any reference to do so ?

Comment: Thanks for the reference it worked ! Its very weird.

Answer (score 0):

This article should help clarify: http://www.htmldog.com/references/html/tags/base/

In theory, you would just trim your iframe's `src` property accordingly:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href="https://www.youtube.com"/>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="embed/xDMP3i36naA?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <img src="img/1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
</body>
```

BUT this will create conflicts when you try to use any other relative paths, like in your `img src` - since you've set `<base href="https://www.youtube.com"/>`, your `img` relative path will literally point to `https://www.youtube.com/img/1.png` - I assume that's not what you want...

Probably better to just put the whole video URL in your iframe `src` and ditch the `<base />` declaration altogether.

Comment: Sorry I forgot tp chip the base url in iframe , by doing so iframe and img is also picking up [https://youtube.com/img/..](https://youtube.com/img/..) which i dont want to happen.